# How to define initial values according to generic value?

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core

I have a generic entity class.

- if T is guid, I want to initialize new guid value .
- if T is int, I want to initialize id =0;
- if T is string  I want to initialize id =string.empty

What is the most suitable way to do this ?

```
public class BaseEntity<T>{

 public string Id { get; set; } ;

  public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
 
  public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }= DateTime.Now;

  public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using the `default` keyword to create an instance of any given type at runtime. However, with your given examples, your intentions may not simply be limited to avoiding unset properties.

Given that possibility, you could dynamically create the desired type and box/unbox it to trick the compiler - such as the example I've provided below.

This isn't generally recommended becuase of it's limited scope and general un-maintainability and error-pronedness.

You have other options as well such as creating generic instances using reflection, this may not be ideal since you have *very* specific "default" values that using reflection may just increase the complexity of the problem more than using a `switch()`(depending on your target framework, or `if/else`(like the example i've provided below.)

```cs
    public class BaseEntity<T>
    {

        public T Id { get; set; } = (T)GetDefault<T>();

        public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
        
        private static object GetDefault<U>()
        {
            Type paramType = typeof(U);
            
            if(paramType == typeof(string))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else if(paramType == typeof(Guid))
            {
                return Guid.NewGuid();
            }
            
            return default(U);
        }
    }
```